# Verify user is Eventbrite attendee when creating new WordPress account

Tags: user-registration

I've created a WordPress site for a ProductCamp. Users register for the event on Eventbrite and then use the WordPress site to vote for breakout sessions. Is there a way to verify that a user is already an attendee in Eventbrite when they are signing up on WordPress?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I'd suggest starting here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to WordPress and PHP, so I was hoping there would be a plugin. I should have specified. Looks like creating one will be fairly difficult based on the answer below (no API request for single attendee).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question. As @andrew pointed out, you need to work with the API at http://developer.eventbrite.com/ to parse member lists with the API during the registration process in WordPress.

But, eventbrite says that "Currently there is no way to search for a specific attendee with event_list_attendees." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366606/verifying-a-single-attendee-with-email

Answer (score 0):

The first link on [the API Documentation of Eventbrite](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/libraries/) ("Getting started") links to various language specific libraries. One of them is [for PHP](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php).

The *first* example in the GitHub Repos `README.md` file is this:

```
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( array(
    'app_key'       => 'YOUR_API_KEY', 
    'client_secret' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    'access_code'   => 'YOUR_ACCESS_CODE',
) );

// request an event by adding a valid EVENT_ID value here:
$resp = $eb_client->event_get( array( 'id' => 'EVENT_ID' ) );

var_dump( $resp );
```

So you simply get back a request object. When you look at the [docs for `event_get`](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_get/), then you'll see that it takes a simple URL to perform the API GET EVENT search:

```
https://www.eventbrite.com/xml/event_get?id=123456789
```

The same goes for the attendee search for a specific event:

```
http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/
```

Then simply utilize the [wp-http-api](/questions/tagged/wp-http-api) (instead of Eventbrites PHP library), perform your request, fetch the result and compare it with your wp/locally stored data.